# "Once I finished" or "Once I have finished"?

Tags: grammar

Someone requested me doing something. I would reply him that

> "I'll do it once I (have) finished it."

Which is correct?

Comment: The grammar aside, I don't understand the meaning. Once you've finished something it's already complete and there there is no reason to do it. *It will be over when it's over* is a common phrase (and the wording gives it meaning), but I don't know how to parse this one. How are *do it* and *finish it* being used differently? Do the two pronouns each refer to something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are grammatical:

> I'll do it once I finish it.
>
> I'll do it once I have finished it.

There isn't much difference between them except that the latter emphasizes the completion or achievement of the action.

However, using "it" twice in these sentences is odd in that it's ambiguous: It means that you're referring to the same thing.

Comment: Agreed about the ambiguity.  A native speaker would generally say something like, "I'll do it once I finish **the other thing**," or maybe, "I'll do **that** once I finish **this**."

Comment: Oh, sorry for that confusion. I should say "I'll do XXX once I finish it.", I meant XXX and it are different things.